# Как отформатировать флэш-диск?

Tags: windows

Windows 7 пишет, что устройство работает нормально, но что объёмы занятой и свободной памяти равны нулю. VID = 1043,  PID = 8006. Предыстория такова: во время переформатирования из FAT32 в NTFS флэшку нечаянно вырвали из USB-разъёма. Теперь никакими программами, распространяемыми в интернете, отформатировать флэшку не удаётся - вся надежда на командную строку (в Linux'e или в Windows).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какими командами и в какой последовательности можно отформатировать в FAT32 или NTFS этот флэш-драйв (USB Flash Drive Cruzer 8GB от SanDisk).

Заранее приношу свои благодарности за помощь.

Comment: Диспетчер дисков смотрели? Может, он просто отмечает флешку как неразмеченный диск?

Comment: К сожалению, Диспетчер дисков флэшку вообще не видит. Если бы видел, то было бы здОрово, это верно! Но за отклик всё равно большое спасибо! 

Comment: http://www.ardamis.com/2009/07/02/usb-drive-unusable-unformattable-and-reporting-0-bytes-capacity/ - посмотрите раздел THE FIX, может поможет?=)

Comment: Большое спасибо за отклик, но скачанная с сайта http://www.ardamis.com/2009/07/02/usb-drive-unusable-unformattable-and-reporting-0-bytes-capacity/ программа сразу после запуска выдаёт сообщение, что к группе флэш-дисков типа U3 моя флэшка не относсится, и к следующей странице переходить отказывается. Т.е. мне остаётся только одно - кликнуть по кнопке CANCEL. 

Увы...

Comment: Не ня .-. А сие: http://remontflash.ru/index.php/2009-11-22-16-33-45/9-2009-12-07-11-25-30/16--usb-flash-linux ?

Comment: К сожалению, дальше выполнения команды dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb дело не идёт. Но и отрицательный результат - это тоже результат, так что спасибо Вам за участие в моей проблеме! Желаю Вам всего самого-самого доброго!

Comment: @Dmitry Не надо добавлять повторяющиеся комментарии. Если Вы хотите исправить комментарий, справа есть специальная кнопка - с ручкой.

Comment: Иван Тенетко: не парься - вставь свою флешку в порт и начни установку винды на нее, не гуманно, зато помогает. не забудь в нужный момент прекратить установку винды. ----- Dmitri: О! Об этом варианте я не подумал :(  ----- Попробую сегодня же. Спасибо большое за совет!

Comment: Начните установку windows, в моем случае - XP2, укажите, что устанавливаете на флешку, и форматируйте, не переживайте, получится, точно-также поступаю в случае, когда флешки запаролены, потом даные вытаскиваются, и все счастливы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дорогие друзья, огромное спасибо всем, кто прислал мне свои советы! Перепробовал всё, что вы предлагали. К сожалению, все попытки воскресить флэшку заканчивались одним и тем же - сообщениями о том, что к использованию она не пригодна. Так что сегодня от дальнейших экспериментов отказался, купил новую (Kingston 16GB), а испорченную сохраню до тех времён, когда найду какой-нибудь хороший софт, предназначенный для восстановления USB Flash Devices. Ещё раз всем огромное спасибо! 
Дмитрий.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте HP Disk Storage Format Tool